# Hubot won' t start after updating scripts

Tags: ubuntu, hubot

i am new to hubot and coffeescript (and javascript as well). I am experimenting hubot and i have an error when trying to launch the bot after updating my scripts (located in /hubotDir/scripts). i copied the error from the shell. I m using Ubuntu 19.04. Thanks in advice

```
audited 179 packages in 1.736s
found 0 vulnerabilities

./hubot: 8: exec: node_modules/.bin/hubot: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, This was fixed with: `npm install hubot`.